# Error no 2 No such file or directory: 'FlightDate'

Tags: python, dataframe, append, concatenation, parquet

I have tried to append and concat a set of parquet files as shown in the code below and I get the error of

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FlightDate'

Does somebody how to fix it?

df = dd.read_csv(
"D:\Desktop2022\CHALLENGEDS\CSV\Combined_Flights_20**.csv",
parse_dates=["FlightDate"],
)
df

The dataframe is created by using dask and parsing the flighdates

```
column_subset = [
    "FlightDate",
    "Airline",
    "Flight_Number_Marketing_Airline",
    "Origin",
    "Dest",
    "Cancelled",
    "Diverted",
    "CRSDepTime",
    "DepTime",
    "DepDelayMinutes",
    "OriginAirportID",
    "OriginCityName",
    "OriginStateName",
    "DestAirportID",
    "DestCityName",
    "DestStateName",
    "TaxiOut",
    "TaxiIn",
    "CRSArrTime",
    "ArrTime",
    "ArrDelayMinutes",
]

dfs = []
for f in df:
    dfs.append(pd.read_parquet(f, columns=column_subset))
df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
FileNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1cf0741b5656> in <module>
     25 dfs = []
     26 for f in df:
     27     dfs.append(pd.read_parquet(f, columns=column_subset))
     28 df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py in read_parquet(path, engine, columns, use_nullable_dtypes, **kwargs)
    457     """
    458     impl = get_engine(engine)
    459     return impl.read(
    460         path, columns=columns, use_nullable_dtypes=use_nullable_dtypes, **kwargs
    461     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py in read(self, path, columns, use_nullable_dtypes, storage_options, **kwargs)
    212                 )
    213 
    214         path_or_handle, handles, kwargs["filesystem"] = _get_path_or_handle(
    215             path,
    216             kwargs.pop("filesystem", None),

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py in _get_path_or_handle(path, fs, storage_options, mode, is_dir)
     80         # fsspec resources can also point to directories
     81         # this branch is used for example when reading from non-fsspec URLs
     82         handles = get_handle(path_or_handle, mode, is_text=False)
     83         fs = None
     84         path_or_handle = handles.handle

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    649         else:
    650             # Binary mode
    651             handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
    652         handles.append(handle)
    653 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FlightDate'
```

Comment: and what is `df` in `for f in df:`?

Comment: @mozway thanks for your reply. below is the definition of df                                      
                                                                                                                                       df = dd.read_parquet(
    "D:\Desktop2022\CHALLENGEDS\MULTIPLE\Combined_Flights_20**.parquet",
    parse_dates=["FlightDate"],
    engine="pyarrow",
)
df